# HexString to packed EBCDIC string

Tags: python, encoding, codec

I need to convert '767f440128e1a00a' hex data to packed EBCDIC string. I want all `result` outcomes into one string but python is giving Unicode error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: unexpected end of data`

```
s='767f440128e1a00a'
output = []
DDF = [1]
distance = 0
for y in range (1,len(s[2:])):
    for x in DDF:
        if s[2:][distance:x*2+distance]!='':
            output.append(s[2:][distance:x*2+distance]) 
        else:
            continue
        distance += x*2
print(output)
final=[]
result=''
bytearrya=[]
for x in output:
    result=(str(bytearray.fromhex(x).decode()))
    x = codecs.decode(x, "hex")
    final.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code based on [Python byte representation of a hex string that is EBCDIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012503/python-byte-representation-of-a-hex-string-that-is-ebcdic) that mentioned "According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html), you need to use 'cp500' for decoding"

```
Codec / Aliases                            / Languages
cp500 / EBCDIC-CP-BE, EBCDIC-CP-CH, IBM500 / Western Europe
```

```
my_string_in_hex = '767f440128e1a00a'
my_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(my_string_in_hex)
print(my_bytes)

my_string = my_bytes.decode('cp500')
print(my_string)
```

Output:

[image]