# Python flask API to receive hex data

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a python api which will receive a hexadecimal data like below:

```
AA213FD51B3801043FBC
```

I have to further decode to make it human readable string which I can do easily. Normally I have designed flask api to receive json data like below:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    raw_data = request.get_json()
```

but not sure how to receive hex data. Can anyone please suggest any idea. Thanks

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` header on the incoming request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364186/hexstring-to-packed-ebcdic-string/58364937#58364937 might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can receive hexdata as a string and then use the int function to turn the value into a number with base 10

```
int('AA213FD51B3801043FBC',16)
```

to convert it to a hex number with base 16 apply

```
hex(int('AA213FD51B3801043FBC',16))
```

you can then use it for hex calculations
e.g.

```
hex(int('AA213FD51B3801043FBC',16)) + hex(10)
```